# Manifolds supporting finite order diffeomorphisms (a local construction?)

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, ds.dynamical-systems

The following question is mainly inspired by this previous one  [Which manifolds admit a diffeomorphism of order $n$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30425/which-manifolds-admit-a-diffeomorphism-of-order-n) and some answers given there.

For $d\geq 2$, let $\mathbb{B}^d$ denote the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ be its boundary.

Question: Does there exist a diffeomorphisms $f\colon\mathbb{B}^d\to\mathbb{B}^d$ such that $f\big|_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}=id$, $f^n=id$ but $f^{n-1}\neq id$, for some $n\geq 2$? Or more precisely, for which $d$ such a diffeomorphism could exist?

I'm interested in such diffeomorphisms because these could be used to build finite order diffeomorphisms on any $d$-manifold (by local construction).

I know, the answer to my question is NO for $d=2$, but I don't know how to prove it in higher dimensions.

On the other hand, after Ian Agol answer to the question [Which manifolds admit a diffeomorphism of order $n$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30425/which-manifolds-admit-a-diffeomorphism-of-order-n), I guess that there should be some closed $3$-manifold not admitting any finite order diffeomorphism different from identity, but I don't know how to construct an explicit example of such a $3$-manifold.

Comment: No, such a diffeomorphism cannot exist in any dimension. The main point is that if $f:M\to M$ is a diffeomorphism of finite order then at any point in the fixed-point set of $f$ the manifold $M$ has coordinates with respect to which $f$ is linear.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie, thanks for your answer. But is there any "topological proof"? I mean, what about finite order homeomorphisms?

Comment: It is a part of Smith theory that fixed point set of a periodic homeomorphism of prime period of an n-sphere is itself a homology manifold. It's dimension is strictly less than n if the action is effective. This rules out (via reflection trick) periodic homeomorphisms of the closed disk fixing the boundary pointwise.

Comment: Here is a less garbled version of what I wrote above: Suppose that $f: D^n\to D^n$ is a periodic homeomorphism fixing the boundary pointwise. After taking a power of $f$ if necessary, we can assume that $f$ is periodic with prime period $p$. Extend $f$ by identity to the rest of $S^n$. Now, apply Smith theory to this (see e.g. Bredon's "Compact transformation groups"): The fixed-point set $F(f)$ will be a $k$-dimensional $Z_p$-homology manifold (also $Z_p$-homology sphere). However, since $F(f)$ contains an open $n$-disk, $k=n$, hence, $f=Id$.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie: can you suggest a standard reference for the local linearity of f of finite order around a fixed point that you mentioned? I need to reference this fact for an article.

Comment: No. But here is a neat way to explain the proof: Let $\mathfrak m$ be the vector space of all germs of smooth functions vanishing at the point $x$. The projection $\frak m\to \frak m/\frak m^2$ to the cotangent space respects the $G$-action. Choosing coordinates means choosing a right inverse $s:\frak m/\frak m^2\to \frak m$. Choosing coordinates that linearize the action means choosing $s$ to respect the action. This can be done if $G$ is finite (or compact): choose some $s$ and then average $g^{-1}sg$ over the group.